# .htaccess redirecting requests to the same folder

Tags: .htaccess, duplicates, directory

I want to use `.htaccess`to redirect **different** requests to the **same** folder.
E.g.:

`domain.de/ordner1/fileX.html`

`domain.de/en/folder1/fileX.html`

`domain.de/it/casella1/fileX.html`

So whenever something is requested out of `/ordner1/`, `/folder1/` or `/casella1/` I want `.htaccess` to fetch the requested file out of a specific directory like `domain.de/all/fileX.html`.

I want to prevent duplicate content but also keep the foldernames in the selected language.
Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#skip css, js etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)[NC] 
#if request to ordner or folder1 or casella1, serve the file from all/
RewriteRule ^(ordner1|en/folder1|it/casella1)/(.+)$ all/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Great, it works! BUT the css and the script files are not loading correctly (maybe wrong paths?) ...

Comment: Or call your js/css with absolute path : use : `http://domain.com/css/style.css` instead of `/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1):

In your docroot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^(ordner1/|en/folder1/|it/casella1/)(.*$)  all/$2  [L]
```

You would need to add extra names to map other translation equivalents.